# excel: Cannot save or export xml data. The xml map in this workbook are not exportable

Tags: xml, excel

I want to export data back to an XML file, after some modification to data I imported from some other XML file (those first line variables never change).

When I click Developer >> export

Excel shows:

> cannot save or export XML data. The XML maps in this workbook are not
>   exportable.

This happes even when I do nothing to modify the data.

I watched several export tutorials on YouTube, but none cover my problem.

Answer (score 13):

The usual reason is the Excel doesn't understand very complicated XML.

From [office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/export-xml-data-HP010206401.aspx):

> An XML mapping cannot be exported if the mapped element’s relationship with other elements cannot be preserved. This relationship may not be preserved for the following reasons:
>
> The schema definition of a mapped element is contained within a sequence with the following attributes:
>
> - The maxoccurs attribute is not equal to 1.
> - The sequence has more than one direct child element defined, or has another compositor as a direct child.
> - Nonrepeating sibling elements with the same repeating parent element are mapped to different XML tables.
> - Multiple repeating elements are mapped to the same XML table, and the repetition is not defined by an ancestor element.
> - Child elements from different parents are mapped to the same XML table.
>
> Additionally, the XML mapping cannot be exported if it contains one of the following XML schema constructs:
>
> **List of lists**
>
> - One list of items contains a second list of items.
>
> **Denormalized data**
>
> - An XML table contains an element that has been defined in the schema to occur once (the maxoccurs attribute is set to 1). When you add such an element to an XML table, Excel fills the table column with multiple instances of the element.
>
> **Choice**
>
> - A mapped element is part of a  schema construct.

Comment: Delete some starting columns and try exporting again. Worked for me

Answer (score 5):

In my case i wanted to export a simple table as an xml file without a prior existing xsd or xml file. So i did this

1. Create an xsd file (see sample below)
2. Import this xsd into excel
3. Relate nodes in the xml structure to a column (see screen below)
4. Export sheet as a xml file

#### Step 1  create an xsd file

I wrote the following xsd in an editor and saved it to a file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Sample_XML_Export">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Foo" type="xsd:int"/>
              <xsd:element name="Bar" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="Baz" type="xsd:int" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

#### Step 2 Import xsd file

This xsd file must be imported into excel. You need to [activate the developer tab in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45). On this tab you can import from XML source (see button "XML...").

[image: Import_XSD]

After you imported the xsd file you will see a tree structure (see folder
`Root` and `Sample_XML_Export`).

#### Step 3 map xml nodes to columns

Now you need to relate a node below `Sample_XML_Export` to an excel-column. Select a node and right click it to map this node to a column

[image: Relate column step 1]

Now select the column you want to map / to relate to the node by clicking on the column header.

[image: Relate column step 2]

#### Step 4 save as xml

Under File / Save as or Export you can save the xls file as an xml file.
This is the exported xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <Sample_XML_Export>
        <Foo>1234</Foo>
        <Bar>122</Bar>
        <Baz>12</Baz>
    </Sample_XML_Export>
    <Sample_XML_Export>
        <Foo>4567</Foo>
        <Bar>144</Bar>
        <Baz>13</Baz>
    </Sample_XML_Export>
    <Sample_XML_Export>
        <Foo>7890</Foo>
        <Bar>187</Bar>
        <Baz>14</Baz>
    </Sample_XML_Export>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. It was a simple sheet and contained just 8 columns but the XML export kept throwing this error. I found that if the order in which the elements appeared in the XML schema did not match the order in which the columns appeared in the sheet, I got this error. I rearranged the columns in my sheet to be the same as the order of elements in the schema & the export became successful.

Answer (score 0):

On a lot of webpages there are instructions for how to export to xml (example: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/xml.html). When I was creating a schema for a pre-existing data I ran across the following.

1. forgot to have a single outer wrapper tag for the rows (main reason for the error that brought me to this page)
2. didn't get the data types right (what looked like numeric was actually text - more of a nuisance I think, but I fixed it first).

Your XML that gets converted to a schema should look like this (I don't know if it needs two "sample rows" but it helps with remembering the outer tag):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<singleOuterWrapperTag>
    <rowTag>
        <columnA>Data Type (numeric, text)</columnA>
        <columnB>Data Type</columnB>
    </rowTag>
    <rowTag>
        <columnA>Data Type (numeric, text)</columnA>
        <columnB>Data Type</columnB>
    </rowTag>
</singleOuterWrapperTag>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'll contribute my solution here.  Of course, it might not be yours, but it is useful info nevertheless, and I'm sure it will help someone.

I found that, in situations where I imported an XML instance instead of a schema, Excel would incorrectly (as in not what I intended) infer the schema from that instance.  This was because the record which I wanted to be repeatable had only one instance within the XML I used to create the map.  (I am creating a template here for future imports, not trying to import existing data just yet, so I only had one record with some dummy data in it.)  I simply copied the record with the dummy data underneath its first instance so that there were two records... and everything was golden.  Imports, and exports, suddenly worked.

Just a note for those of you in the same boat as I was.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when I had an XSD element commented out in the schema. When I removed the commented out element it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me, you need to remove the filter