# open XML and make some changes, then export the new XML by EXCEL 2010 in Win 7

Tags: xml, excel, windows-7, excel-2010

I need to export XML to XML by EXCEL 2010 in Win 7.
I import XML file to EXCEL 2010, then I need to make some changes and then export the changed XML files.

I got the problem:

```
  "Cannot save or export XML data. The XML maps in this workbook are not exportable."
```

My question is simialr as

[excel: Cannot save or export xml data. The xml map in this workbook are not exportable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794136/excel-cannot-save-or-export-xml-data-the-xml-map-in-this-workbook-are-not-expo)

But, only the reasons for the problem are given there, no solutions.  I am new to XML.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to make some changes to an xml file, Excel is not a good program to work with xml. Try using Notepad++ or just regular Notepad. XML is just text.