# Runtime 1004 Application Defined or Object Defined Error during NewBook.SaveAs

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a command button macro that takes the worksheet (only one of several in the workbook) that has the button, creates a copy, replaces the formulas with the values, and saves two copies of the worksheet.  I tried using code I found elsewhere here, but when the macro gets to the  SaveAs line, it errors out.

Most of this was from a previous question I asked, but I have not been able to figure out what I am not seeing or have messed up.  Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub SaveAuth1_Click()
'   Saves the Authorization in the Current Year's Pay Estimate Folder in
'   Dave's Snapserver Construction Files
'   Then clears the form, hides the form, and quits Excel.

Dim AFName As String   'this will be the name of the new file name saved in the Pay Estimates Folder
Dim AFfolder As String 'This is the folder to save the form into
Dim AFDate As String   'This is the date to choose which year's folder to use
Dim afile As String     ' This is the full file name to be saved.
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("BLR 13210")

If ws.Range("E15") = "" Then
    ans = MsgBox("This form is not ready to be saved", vbOKOnly, "BLR 13210")
    Select Case ans
        Case vbOK
        Exit Sub
    End Select
End If

'**** TRIAL is added here until project is compelted.
AFName = "TRIAL" & Worksheets("Initial Entry").Range("B5") & " " & "Authorization " & _
    ws.Range("G17") & " - " & ws.Range("E15")
ans = MsgBox(AFName, vbOKCancel)
Select Case ans
    Case vbCancel
        Exit Sub
    Case vbOK
        GoTo Line1
End Select

Line1:
' Saves a copy of the form into Daves Snapserver folders and then prompts the SaveAs dialog box
' to save a second copy in the user's files.

AFDate = Year(Now())
AFfolder = "M:\DotserverD\Daves Snapserver Files Construction Files\" & AFDate & " Pay Estimates"

Debug.Print AFfolder
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Creates new workbook
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BLR 13210").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
' Replaces the referenced formula values with the actual values (removes reference to other sheet)
With NewBook.Sheets("BLR 13210").UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With

' Deletes buttons from the bid tab worksheet being saved
Dim Shp As Shape
For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Shp.Delete
Next Shp

' removes warning about saving worksheet with macros as .xlsx format and possibly deleting data.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

' Deletes unused worksheets
Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
Worksheets("Sheet3").Delete

afile = AFfolder & "\" & AFName
Debug.Print afile
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=afile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook   '<---  Runtime error 1004 Application/object defined

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Workbooks(AFName).Close (True)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show

ans = MsgBox("Proceed?", vbOKCancel)
Select Case ans
    Case vbCancel
        Exit Sub
    Case vbOK
        GoTo Line2
End Select
```

Comment: Not every workbook can be saved as xml. Might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794136/excel-cannot-save-or-export-xml-data-the-xml-map-in-this-workbook-are-not-expo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling you need to add  the extention to this:
    `AFName = "TRIAL" & Worksheets("Initial Entry").Range("B5") & " " & "Authorization " & _
    ws.Range("G17") & " - " & ws.Range("E15")`

`afile = AFfolder & "\" & AFName & ".xlsx"`

EDIT:

Problem was identified in the String AFname:

ws.range("E15") had dates formatted with the '/' character. excel is unable to save the book with the illegal character. Adjusted the format to be dates formatted with dashes.

Comment: I would get the error when I had the extension in there too.

Comment: can you give me an example of an AFILE string? im having trouble duplicating the error. Perhaps the afolder, driven by the date, is an invalid location. i also noticed you did not declare newbook as a workbook variable.

Comment: This is from the debug.print...
AFfolder = M:\DotserverD\Daves Snapserver Files Construction Files\2017 Pay Estimates

afile = M:\DotserverD\Daves Snapserver Files Construction Files\2017 Pay Estimates\TRIAL16-00470-00-RS Authorization 1 - 9/30/2016

Just now when I ran it I got the "SaveAs method of Workbook Class failed"

Comment: file names cannot have the '/' character. You need to reformat that date in the last portion of the file name to be dashes perhaps.

Comment: Scott,  this worked.  I have now required the date to use "-" instead and it worked perfectly.  Thank you!