# error when trying to export excel sheet to XML

Tags: xml, excel

when i try to export some excel sheets to XML , i receive this message (cannot save or export XML data , the XML maps in this workbook are not exportable)

please , could someone give me a solution for this problem

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17093273/2319299

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel: Cannot save or export xml data. The xml map in this workbook are not exportable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794136/excel-cannot-save-or-export-xml-data-the-xml-map-in-this-workbook-are-not-expo)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Ragni , you gave me the reasons , but you didnt give me the solutions .